# accessing multiple twitter user profiles in python

Tags: python, json, twitter

So I am trying to access twitter's API to get user specific profile information for a list of user ID's that I have.
the following code seems to work for that and I am able to get a json data output. My question is if I can do this for several users(several 1000's) and if so how to get them in a table format?

Here is the code with the resulting output for 1 user

```
def get_user_profile(twitter_api, screen_names=None, user_ids=None):

    # Must have either screen_name or user_id (logical xor)
    assert (screen_names != None) != (user_ids != None), \
    "Must have screen_names or user_ids, but not both"

    items_to_info = {}

    items = screen_names or user_ids

    while len(items) > 0:

        # Process 100 items at a time per the API specifications for /users/lookup.
        # See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/lookup for details.

        items_str = ','.join([str(item) for item in items[:100]])
        items = items[100:]

        if screen_names:
            response = make_twitter_request(twitter_api.users.lookup, 
                                            screen_name=items_str)
        else: # user_ids
            response = make_twitter_request(twitter_api.users.lookup, 
                                            user_id=items_str)

        for user_info in response:
            if screen_names:
                items_to_info[user_info['screen_name']] = user_info
            else: # user_ids
                items_to_info[user_info['id']] = user_info

    return items_to_info

response = get_user_profile(twitter_api, screen_names=["Juniorsantanab1"])

print json.dumps(response, indent=1)
```

Output:

```
{
 "Juniorsantanab1": {
  "follow_request_sent": false, 
  "profile_use_background_image": true, 
  "default_profile_image": true, 
  "id": 2565811553, 
  "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", 
  "verified": false, 
  "profile_text_color": "333333", 
  "profile_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_4_normal.png", 
  "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", 
  "entities": {
   "description": {.......etc
```

Comment: You are on the right track. Start a loop through users that you want to download and start writing the 200 OK responses to a file. Once you hit the rate limit stop, then start again 15 minutes later.

Comment: also any idea how i can get the json data directly into a dataframe format with user ids and the corresponding profile attributes as the different columns?thanks

Comment: Twitter data often has missing or deprecated fields. Just leave it in json format to store it directly. Then once you have all the data that you want collected you can easily export it to csv format or similar.